# dropdown value selecting only first value

Tags: c#

In the below C# code even though I am choosing my own year but still the value is passed as 1920 only. I can see all the values being displayed in the dropdown box but when I choose a value and submit it only 1920 is being passed to the database.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1920; i <= 2000; i++)
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        sbtc.dex(DropDownList3.SelectedItem);        
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where did I do mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you click on the button it is again executing the code in your `Page_Load` event. Solution is to set the dropdown values only once. You can use `Page.IsPostBack` property to check whether this is the initial load or a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 1920; i <= 2000; i++)
        {
            DropDownList3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
if(!IsPostBack)
[
    for (int i = 1920; i <= 2000; i++)
    {
       DropDownList3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also setting a value for the selected items like this, make sure to check for postbacks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1920; i <= 2000; i++)
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Add( new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
            }
   }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   sbtc.dex(DropDownList3.SelectedItem);        
}
```